# Is there a library that implements the "Mickey Mouse Version" of asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: public-key

Here is what I mean with "Mickey Mouse Version":

> 1. `CHARLIE` makes a keypair `key1` and `key2`
> 2. `CHARLIE` sends `key1` to `ALICE`
> 3. `CHARLIE` sends `key2` to `BOB`
> 4. `ALICE` encrypts a `custom message` with `key1` into `code`
> 5. `ALICE` sends `code` to `BOB`
>
>    - => that's true `one-way encryption`
>    - => (`ALICE` has no way to decrypt the message again)
> 6. `BOB` decrypts `code` with `key2` into the original `custom message`
>
>    - => that's true `one-way decryption`
>    - => (`BOB` has no way to encrypt the message again)

**QUESTIONS**

1. can this be done with elliptic curve crypto?
2. **if not:** can this be done with any asymmetric cryptography library you are aware of? (preferrable of course javascript)
3. **if not:** is it possible that there is literature that describe a way to do this?

---

I'm sorry - it's my first time and maybe the title wasn't chosen well and also I don't need a library (I guess I can find one myself and also language is secondary), but rather a more general answer - hope that makes it better :-)

**Otherwise** to answer to the given comments:
1. With "one-way decryption" i mean that if BOB deletes the received code after he decrypted the custom message, he cant create the exact same deleted code from the custom message
2. Also, forget about "again", this was from a "global view" on the given scenario, because ALICE encrypted it already - but that's just me using unfortunate ways to describe things.
3. I am aware that the first 3 steps are cryptographycally problematic, but i'm interested in the steps (4. to 6.) and just wanted to shorten the description, so basically imagine the first 3 steps haven in a secure way :-)

hope that helps and makes the question a bit better and clearer.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Note that we have a [policy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what's on topic, and code recommendation is out of it. Also _"of course (language X)"_ is borderline trolling for whatever X, (and may I say especially for X). Are you aware that if communication in steps 3 and 5 is intercepted (the default assumption in crypto), confidentiality of `custom message` is lost?

Comment: Back to the question: what does it mean that _"`BOB` has no way to encrypt the message again"_ ? Bob has not encrypted previously, thus _"again"_ is meaningless. Also, if Bob has a message, he unavoidably can encrypt it using a cipher and key of his choice. What _exactly_ should Bob be prevented from doing? Also, what do you mean by (true) _"`one-way decryption`"_?

Comment: As usual, I think you may need additional signature generation / verification and maybe timestamping or signatures by a trusted third party such as Charlie. Usually we don't have a Charlie that generates key pairs for the participants though, as private keys are generally, well, kept private.

Comment: Thank you @Maarten-reinstateMonica :-)
I know that the above scenario is an **unusual scenario**, but I don't want to use public/private keys in the traditional sense. It's about the "one-way decryption", which means if BOB ever deletes or loses `code`, he can't create it from the decrypted `custom message`, but needs to ask ALICE to send it again.

Comment: "but I don't want to use public/private keys in the traditional sense" sorry, but that's not a goal, whichever way you spin it. If you use signing and time stamping, then you **can** create a unique code, right? What is the *practical difference* in dismissing a message because the signature is not right compared to dismissing it because it cannot be decrypted with a specific private key?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for then is a cryptosystem where the public and private key are related, but the public key can be generated at another location than the private key's location. Or where such a key pair can be generated by charlie and then distributed. Hmmm.

Comment: if the keys can be related but generated independently, that would be great, but i assumed this does not exist and that's why charlie generates the keys - of course, distributing the keys to bob and alice should be more secure, but that is the easy part, so i wanted to keep it short.

my bigger problem is the part where alice and bob use the keys in the presented way and this is where i struggle

Comment: @fgrieu It means he cannot un-decrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about a cryptosystem that is similar to a public key encryption system, except that the "private key" (or decryption key) cannot be used to encrypt.

One way to get this sort of functionality is using a conventional public key encryption and signatures.  That is, Alice would get an encryption public key and a signature private key; while Bob would get the corresponding decryption private key and signature verification public key.  Alice would encrypt the message, and then sign it (and Alice cannot decrypt the message; she doesn't have the decryption key).  Bob would verify the signature and decrypt the message.  The idea is that we would not consider that a valid encrypted message unless it had Alice's signature on it (which Bob cannot generate) - would that address whatever problem you're trying to solve?

Assuming that, for whatever reason, the above solution is inapplicable, well, what you asked for can obviously be done; one example would be "large exponent RSA"; that is, Charlies would generate two large primes $p, q$ (e.g. 1024 bits each), and select two large values $d, e$ (e.g. circa 2048 bits each) with $d \cdot e \equiv 1 \pmod{ \text{lcm}( p-1, q-1 ) }$, and give Alice the values $p \times q$ and $e$, and Bob the values $p \times q$ and $d$ (and encryption/decryption proceeds from that point essentially as RSA public key encryption, albeit without certain optimizations that we generally use.

I don't know of any libraries that have this functionality already.

You also ask if you can do this functionality with elliptic curve crypto; ignoring the idea of doing the above RSA functionality within an elliptic curve group (which is rather slower, and no more secure), there is no immediately obvious way to do this.  The immediate problem we run into is that, in ECC, the private key is usually an integer $a$, while the public key is the point $aG$ (that is, the generator point $G$ added to itself $a$ times).  The problem with this is if you have the private key $a$, you can immediately compute the public key $aG$; this is not usually an issue with public key encryption, but it is in this case.

Comment: Note: in the answer, the problem of passive eavesdropping is addressed for the "sends" of step 5, but not for the "sends" of steps 2 and/or 3: eavesdropping this, even passively, allows later attacks. In the _conventional public key encryption and signatures_ method, we can solve this issue as conventionally done: by generating private keys on the Alice/Bob sides rather than Charlie at steps 2/3. That seems far from trivial, perhaps impossible, in the _large exponent RSA_ method. It seems that steps 2/3 should be protected by distinct means.

Comment: i agree that step 2 and 3 are not secure, but each party could have a traditional public/private key pair, do a diffie hellman with each other and then send each other messages through a secure channel, but it would make the description above a lot more verbose.
The part i want to solve is step 4-6 and because i believe there is no way to generate private keys that are related independently of each other, i just used charlie to create the keys instead - if there is a way, then i'm open to that too :-)

But the main problem i want to see solved is how alice and bob use the keys :-)

Comment: thank you @poncho :-)
so the signature example you describe would not work, because as far as i understand, BOB would not need to be able to discard `code` entirely, but he could discard the majority and just keep the signature and then encrypt the `custom message` he has and add the `signature` he kept and he is fine.

this is not good enough. I really want to be able to force bob to keep the entire `code` around

Comment: Otherwise: So you are saying the above could work with RSA - but there might be no implementation for it yet. Do you have a recommendation of how to get one?
Given your description, I could try to find a library and fork it and see if i can add the feature - but usually they say i'm not supposed to roll my own crypto :D

So what would be the best way of getting this feature?